# Configuring vscode to debug html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug some html/javascript using vscode.

I have installed the chrome debugger extension and configured the launch.json
as

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [


        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "port": 4000,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:4000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "sourceMaps": true
        }

    ]
}
```

The page is being served by express. When I run debug, vscode launches chrome and fetches the page, however it ignores any breakpoints in the code. (I've been using the same vscode installation to debug some python and it seems fine.)

I'm not sure it is relevant but the code is below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Force-Directed graph</title>
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    root;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

//Added markers to indicate that this is a directed graph
svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["arrow"])
    .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 4)
    .attr("markerHeight", 4)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

d3.json("graph.json", function(json) {
  root = json;
  //Give nodes ids and initialize variables
  for(var i=0; i<root.nodes.length; i++) {
    var node = root.nodes[i];
    node.id = i;
    node.collapsing = 0;
    node.collapsed = false;
  }
  //Give links ids and initialize variables
  for(var i=0; i<root.links.length; i++) {
    var link = root.links[i];
    link.source = root.nodes[link.source];
    link.target = root.nodes[link.target];
    link.id = i;
  }

  update();
});

function update() {
  //Keep only the visible nodes
  var nodes = root.nodes.filter(function(d) {
    return d.collapsing == 0;
  });
  var links = root.links;
  //Keep only the visible links
  links = root.links.filter(function(d) {
    return d.source.collapsing == 0 && d.target.collapsing == 0;
  });

  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

  // Update the links…
  link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Exit any old links.
  link.exit().remove();

  // Enter any new links.
  link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; })
      .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");

  // Update the nodes…
  node = node.data(nodes, function(d){ return d.id; }).style("fill", color);

  // Exit any old nodes.
  node.exit().remove();

  // Enter any new nodes.
  node.enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })
      .style("fill", color)
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);
}

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

// Color leaf nodes orange, and packages white or blue.
function color(d) {
  return d.collapsed ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
    //check if link is from this node, and if so, collapse
    root.links.forEach(function(l) {
      if(l.source.id == d.id) {
        if(d.collapsed){
          l.target.collapsing--;
        } else {
          l.target.collapsing++;
        }
      }
    });
    d.collapsed = !d.collapsed;
  }
  update();
}

</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I am not very proficient at vscode debug bridges (mine just works), but having the site at port 4000, and the debug attach at port 4000, seems a bit fishy.

Comment: I replaced the attach with the default which uses port 9222 but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - incorrect webroot. The code was in a subdirectory /public used by express.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem but I solve it in a simple way.

**index.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <section id="message">ok</section>
    <button id="btn">send message to iframe</button>
    <button id="btn2">reload /demo.html in iframe</button>

    <br />

    <script>
     const iframe = document.getElementById("demo");
     iframe.name = "demo";

     const message = document.getElementById("message");
     const button = document.getElementById("btn");
     const button2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
        
     button.addEventListener("click", () => {
       iframe.contentWindow.postMessage("hello");
     });

     button2.addEventListener("click", () => {
       window.open("/demo.html", "demo");
     });

     window.addEventListener("message", (ev) => {
       const data = ev.data;
       message.innerHTML = data;
     });
    </script>

    <iframe id="demo" src="/demo.html" />
</body>
</html>
```

I want to debug this file in vscode, and I use native nodejs module, "http", to create a server to serve this file.

When I visit `http://b.com:8000/index.html`， my server will send index.html to browser.

My `launch.json` looks like:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "launch a website and debug",
        "url": "http://b.com:8000/index.html",
        "webRoot": "${fileDirname}",
      }
    ]
}
```

`webRoot` is necessary.

Before debug, I open index.html in vscode editor, so "${fileDirname}" refers to the directory where index.html is located.

Then I make some breakpoints in javascript codes, start my server, and click debug button in vscode.

As you know, index.html is rendered in browser directly, breakpoints don't work.

To solve this problem, you should make some changes in index.html, it looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <section id="message">ok</section>
    <button id="btn">send message to iframe</button>
    <button id="btn2">reload /demo.html in iframe</button>

    <br />
     
    <script type="module" src="/client.js"></script>

    <iframe id="demo" src="/demo.html" />
</body>
</html>
```

- Put your javascript codes into a single file, such as "client.js";
- Link client.js in index.html, you can use `<script src="/client.js" defer>` instead of `<script type="module" src="/client.js">`;
- make breakpoints in "client.js";

Ok, try to debug again, and it works.

I hope this will help you.